# My code is giving a different out put for leetcode 3sum problem. Can anyone correct my code?

Tags: python

I am trying to solve Leetcode problem '3sum'.

Here is the question:
Given an array nums of n integers, are there elements a, b, c in nums such that a + b + c = 0? Find all unique triplets in the array which gives the sum of zero.
Notice that the solution set must not contain duplicate triplets.

Example:

Input: `nums = [-1,0,1,2,-1,-4]`

Output: `[[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1]]`

Here is my code and output.

```
class Solution:

    def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        
        result = []
        nums.sort()
                      
        for i in range(len(nums)):       
            if nums[i] > 0: 
                break
            if i == 0 or nums[i] != nums[i-1]:
                continue

            left, right = i+1, len(nums)-1

            while left < right:
                prod = nums[i]+nums[left]+nums[right]                
                if prod > 0:    
                    right -= 1
                elif prod < 0:   
                    left += 1
                else:            
                    result.append([nums[i],nums[right],nums[left]])
                    
                    left += 1
                    right-= 1
                    while left < right and nums[left] == nums[left-1]:
                        left += 1
                
        return result
```

Can any one guide me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: It's not obvious to me that your code checks all possible combinations.  I'd recommend adding some logging to it so you can watch how it behaves when it should be finding the missing solution.

Comment: You can use 3 for loops to iterate every combinations.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
Step through your code and narrow down the problem into a [mre]. 
Then ask a specific question. _"Why is my code doing this"_ is [too broad for Stack Overflow.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/843953)
Please also take the [tour], read [ask] and [what's on-topic](/help/on-topic). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 3 nested for loops to iterate through each combination, and sort the numbers and check if the sorted combination is already in the result or not.

```
nums = [-1,0,1,2,-1,-4]
result=[]

for i in range(len(nums)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(nums)):
        for k in range(j+1, len(nums)):
            #print(i, j, k, ':', nums[i], nums[j], nums[k])
            if (nums[i]+ nums[j]+ nums[k])==0:
                #print('***', i, j, k, ':', nums[i], nums[j], nums[k])
                r = sorted([nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]])
                if r not in result:
                    result.append(sorted([nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]]))

print(result)
```

Outpout is:

```
[[-1, 0, 1], [-1, -1, 2]]
```

Comment: ok, this should do the trick

Comment: thank you Malo. it works and easy to understand.